# Getting Module Failure error while running Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, rabbitmq

I am getting the following error when running my Ansible playbook:

1. **hosts file**

```
    [node1]
    rabbit-node1    ansible_ssh_host=x.x.x.x     ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu

    [node2]
    rabbit-node2    ansible_ssh_host=x.x.x.x     ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu

    [node3]
    rabbit-node3    ansible_ssh_host=x.x.x.x     ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu

    [workers]
    rabbit-node2
    rabbit-node3

    [all_group]
    rabbit-node1
    rabbit-node2
    rabbit-node3

    [all:vars]
    ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
    ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
    ansible_private_key_file=private key path
    ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

2. **Error**

```
fatal: [rabbit-node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "setup"}, "module_stderr": "OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for x.x.x.x\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 25400\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\nShared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "  File \"/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1584361123.7-96709661573808/setup\", line 3160\r\n    except OSError, e:\r\n                  ^\r\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

3 **playbook.yml**

Playbook file for Setting hostname installing rabbitmq and creating cluster of rabitmq having 3 nodes.

```
- name: deploy RabbitMQ and setup the environment
  hosts:
    - all_group
  #gather_facts: False
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: yes

  roles:
    - set_hostname
    - install_rabbitmq


- name: Configure RabbitMQ Cluster
  hosts:
    - workers
  user: ubuntu
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - cluster_setup
```

Comment: Can you provide the playbook code?

Comment: Please update your question with the code and not in the comments

Comment: Please format using ```

Comment: I have updated the question, can you please check the playbook.yml file

Comment: The error message explains that the `setup` module is trying to send python source code that the remote python (which appears to be python3 from your question) does not understand. That smells like your local ansible is very, very old; can you include the output of `ansible --version` in your question?

Comment: Ansible version:2.0.0.2